# Xcode XCBuild support error for ionic build

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, code-signing, code-signing-entitlements

I have a ionic project that I am trying to build on iOS.

When running `ionic build ios`, it gives this error:

> FIXME: Implement XCBuild support for macros in overriding parameters
>   with condition sets:
>
> ```
>     CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*] = iPhone Developer
> ```
>
> Error: Error code 1 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/Person/ProjectA/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,ProjectA.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,ProjectA,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/Person/ProjectA/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/Person/ProjectA/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

I have tried:

1. Remove platform and add platform
2. Change `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]` from `iPhone Distributor` to `iPhone Developer` in `build-release.xcconfig`
3. Re-did signing from xcode to try both automatic and manual signing

but all were not successful.

I am running:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
ios-deploy version: 1.9.4 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
Node Version: v4.4.7
Xcode version: Xcode 11.1 Build version 11A1027
```

It is an old ionic version but able to run on my old macbook air (OS: High Sierra). I am now using a new macbook air (OS: Mojave) and trying to setup the environment. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error after re-adding the iOS platform to my project with `cordova@8.1.2`/`cordova-ios@4.5.4`, even with a `build.json` file [included in my project](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/tools.html#signing-the-app). I manually upgraded to `cordova-ios@5.1.1` (by specifying the version in the `cordova platforms add ios@5` command) and the error went away.